# How do you set up dictionary to look like this, given this input?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
animal = Animal([Dog((1, 4)), Frog((5, 7)), Dog((3, 4))])
```

Look like: `{'Dog': [Dog((1, 4)), Dog((3, 4))], 'Frog': [Frog((5, 7))]}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to put the same animals together. This should be done through one traversal:

```
animal_dict = {}
for animal in animal_list:
    if isinstance(animal, Dog):
        animal_dict.setdefault('Dog', []).append(animal)
    elif isinstance(animal, Frog):
        animal_dict.setdefault('Frog', []).append(animal)
    elif ...
```

If you put these classes in a list, you can do it more gracefully:

```
animal_types = [Dog, Frog, ...]
animal_dict = {}
for animal in animal_list:
    for animal_type in animal_types:
        if isinstance(animal, animal_type):
            key = animal_type.__name__
            animal_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(animal)
            break
```

There is also a simple and crude method, but it is not completely equivalent to the previous method, because it does not consider inheritance:

```
animal_dict = {}
for animal in animal_list:
    key = type(animal).__name__
    animal_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(animal)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it for any animal input? Like outside of just frog or dog.

Comment: @Mitch Referring to the second method, collect all animal classes in a list.